# how to know spinner selected value in another Activity

Tags: android

How to get spinner selected value in another screen?

Suppose I have 3 options in Login Screen

1. wifi
2. Gprs
3. SMS

   I select option 3 in Login Screen for spinner value and
   when I go another activity how do I set the spinner value like this manner

   if selected position is 3
   true
   else
   false

Or any other way I make check to know which value is selected on Last screen?

Answer (score 2):

Use  intExtra in intent to pass value (1,2,3) to the second activity, where you can use getIntent().getExtra() to read that int.  Based on its value you know what was selected on spinner.

Example: In LoginActivity:

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("CODE",1);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

In SecondActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int code=intent.getIntExtra("CODE",0);
```

Then based on code value you know what was selected.

Comment: its mean i use this code 3 times 
Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("CODE",1);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();

Comment: No, you use intent.putExtra("CODE",1); if wifi was selected, intent.putExtra("CODE",2); if gprs was selected or intent.putExtra("CODE",3); if SMS was selected.

Comment: this line show error in another acitvity
int code=intent.getIntExtra("CODE");
error is 

The method getIntExtra(String, int) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: is mean  use 3 times this line 

intent.putExtra("CODE",1);
intent.putExtra("CODE",2);

intent.putExtra("CODE",3);

how do i dynemically pas   spinner selected possition to another activity where i set check
if value is 1 do this if value is 2 do this  if value is 3 do this???

Comment: You use that line only once. Go through some tutorials first please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `putExtra()` and `getExtra()` in activity.

Write in your activity where you have to send data.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,YourNextActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("Value", spinnerValue);
  startActivity(intent);
```

While receiving use this

```
String getSpinnerValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Value");
```

Comment: no imean suppose in login screen user select
Selected position =3(which is SMS)
when user go another activity for select positon 3 how 2nd activity knows user come in this activity by select position 3??

Comment: use selected value of spinner(i.e. SMS) in putExtra() to send in 2nd activity.And in 2nd Activity use switch case to identify which option is selected if it is sms then send sms like wise you can do.If you don't get let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the  index of selected item and pass it to next activity.In the second activity  set this item as selected

Answer (score 0):

Passing value from one activity to another activity by means of putExtras() and getExtras()

```
  Intent in=new Intent(currentActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
  in.putExtras("passingvalue_attribute","passvalue");
  startActivity(in);
  finish();
```

For getting value.

```
 String value=getIntent().getExtras().getString("passingvalue_attribute"); // its for string likewise you can send and get boolean and integer also..
```

I think it may helpful to you..

Comment: thats the value which you want to pass from one activity to another activity.

Comment: i user postions in spinner if selected possiton is 3 (SMS) login
when go antoher acitivity show application knows is select spineer 3 position (SMS)

Comment: sorry i cant get you what you are try to say. As my understanding you need to send the message as SMS to another activity when use press position 3 or depends on user press activity should move??

Comment: no no i do not sent parameters i want to know in another acivity i come in this activity by select which value of spinner???

Answer (score 0):

`String selectedItem = YourActivtyName.spinnername.getSelectedItem().toString();`
using static you can access data members in another classes or activity.
in your activity you have to declare the Spinner name as public static.